# How to use multiple data in Meta keyword using php & Mysqli

Tags: php, html

I want to use meta keywords dyanamically so i have a table in mysqli named course and in this many data has been filled like:

```
IAS
RPSC
RAS
UPSC
RSCIT
```

and now i am using this

```
<?php
include("inc/connect.php");
$get_course = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM course");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($get_course)){
 $course_name = $row['c_name'];
$meta_keywords = $course_name;
}
include("inc/header.php");
?>
```

But i am getting only last one value not all value i want in this format like

```
/* i am using this in header */
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $meta_keywords; ?>">
/* i want in this format */
<meta name="keywords" content="ias,ras,rpsc,rscit">
```

so please tell me what is the solution for this.

Comment: This is really absolute beginner-level stuff; IMHO this should not be asked here in the first place. This is basic knowledge you _should_ acquire from working through a couple of beginner’s tutorials (instead of _abusing_ this site as a personal teaching ground.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `array` and `implode` you can do that...

```
<?php
include("inc/connect.php");
$get_course = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM course");
$meta_keywords = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($get_course)){
  $course_name = $row['c_name'];
  $meta_keywords[] = $course_name;
}
include("inc/header.php");
?>
```

and at your template code

```
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo implode(',',$meta_keywords); ?>">
```

please refer: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Comment: Thanks Sir you are Great your code is helped me thank you very much